# Opening child window in WPF MVVM pattern - correct solution?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, dependency-injection, modal-dialog

I was struggling with opening new window in MVVM pattern without violating it's rules for a month. I have read I think every post here and watch every video about this, but as a amateur programmer I did not find easy solution to understand for me.

Finally I came up with solution relying on answers I have found.
There were some conditions that solution had to follow:

1. Dependency injection friendly
2. Not violating MVVM pattern
3. Reusable for multiple views
4. Easy to use (without having to type 100 lines of code for every window).
5. No strict "DialogMVVM" etc. libraries allowed. (I am in learning phase so I wanted to understand what my code is doing.)

*Disclaimer: I do not need getting result from dialog so it is not included here.*

Please tell me if my solution is proper or not.

**1. I made DialogWindow template with DataTemplate:**

```
<Window x:Class="AWH.Views.DialogWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:viewmodels="clr-namespace:AWH.ViewModels" 
        xmlns:views="clr-namespace:AWH.Views"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight">
    <Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewmodels:ProductAddViewModel}">
            <views:ProductView/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>
</Window>
```

**2. IDialogService and implementation in DialogService**

```
public interface IDialogService
{
    void ShowDialog(object viewModel);
}

public class DialogService : IDialogService
{
    public void ShowDialog(object viewModel)
    {
        var win = new DialogWindow();
        win.Content = viewModel;
        win.ShowDialog();
    }
}
```

**3. Opening the window from ViewModel (in this case ProductListViewModel)**

```
public class ProductListViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
        private IDialogService _dialogService;
        private IProductAddViewModel _productAddViewModel;
        public ICommand AddProductCommand { get; set; }

        public ProductListViewModel(IDialogService dialogService, IProductAddViewModel productAddViewModel)
        {
            _productAddViewModel = productAddViewModel;
            _dialogService = dialogService;
    
            AddProductCommand = new DelegateCommand(OpenAddProductDialog);
        }

        private void OpenAddProductDialog()
        {
        _dialogService.ShowDialog(_productAddViewModel);
        }
}
```

**4. Injecting dependencies in App.xaml.cs (I am using IServiceCollection)**

```
        services.AddSingleton<ProductListViewModel>();
        services.AddSingleton<IProductAddViewModel, ProductAddViewModel>();
        services.AddSingleton<IDialogService, DialogService>();
```

Thats it. If I thinking correctly I am not violating MVVM pattern because viewmodel is not calling view it is calling viewmodel and WPF is doing the rest via DataTemplates.

Am I right?

EDIT: Of course you need a way to open this window from some other view. So (in this case) ProductListView.xaml (this is a view corresponding to ProductListViewModel):

```
    <Button Content="Add product" Margin="10 15" Padding="8 5" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Command="{Binding AddProductCommand}" />
```

Comment: My preference is a panel in the main window and a single window app  literally single. But if you want a dialogue then you should think about how you make the window the user is interacting with it's owner.

Comment: MVVM: open the Window from the view (code-behind). Usually dialogs are opened when the user clicks a button. Bind the content of this dialog to your view model.

Comment: If you have to show a dialog (which is a module of the View) from your View Model, then something might be wrong with your application design. View Model should not depend on the View nor should it implement its responsibilities like UI logic (if you  want to write 100% MVVM compliant applications).

Comment: To be honest I do not understand. Where my View Model is depending on a view? If I am correct this solution works as follows: Click button in MainWindow that have binding to a command in MainViewModel -> Pass ViewModel to DialogService that is creating new DialogWindow and passing this ViewModel as DialogWindow.Conent. As DialogWindow have DataTemplate for this ViewModel it is displaing corresponding view for it. I think there is no place in the code that ViewModel know about a view.

Comment: Your view model is the component that controls the dialog. It actually actively participates in displaying the dialog. And this is not necessary: user clicks button -> event handler/routed command in view handles click and creates the dialog to display it. the rest depends on your design: when dialog is closed, view can pass the result (e.g. dialog's view model) to the e.g. main view's view model. Alternatively the dialog is fire&forget and closing it will commit the changes via command (in this case the dialog's view model instead of the main view's view model knows how to handle the input).

Comment: This is just one example how the flow could look like. As long as the view model is passive towards the view the solution could be fine in terms of MVVM. In your  current scenario, the view model knows a type that creates and handles dialogs/views.

Comment: You should use the the '@' to address a member like '@Świętopeł Ziemowit'
 . Otherwise nobody gets a notification to reply. Just passed by by accident, because this page was opened in a tab which I wanted to close.

Comment: You can put all the dialog logic into the MainWIndow (or a class that the MainWindow can use). Then let MainWIndow expose a routed command and register it with a CommandBinding. then any view or element that is a child of MainWindow can invoke this command to, for example, show a dialog. You can use the DialogService from the MainWindow.

Comment: @BionicCode Still don't get it. I am really frustrated about those dialogs in MVVM - it is pain in my ass. Also there is as many theories as many people saying those about violating MVVM pattern. One of theory is that I should not put any code in view's code behind (xaml.cs) and that's why I handled it in ViewModel via CommandBinding. 

I know my ViewModel is taking part in opening dialog window, but still its only passing viewmodel type, not view type. I will be pleased if you post example code based on mine.

Comment: Code.-behind is a C#compiler feature which is realized view the `partial` keyword. It has nothing to do with any design pattern. It's just a language feature. Every control makes use of it. What is relevant to MVVM is where the application's responsibilities are moved to. The view model is an application component that only freaks with the model. It is never allowed to handle controls or classes that do it. Every view related code behind to the view component and it's therefore not available for the view model. I will post a small example. Just have to finish a task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the context of *MVVM* a dialog is a module of the *View* component. Following the rules of *MVVM*, the *View Model* component is not allowed to handle controls or implement UI related logic. This means, a class of the *View Model* is also not allowed to use another class that does handle controls or implements UI logic, as such a class would be part of the *View* component.

Controls must always be instantiated and handled in the *View* component.

The definition of a design pattern requires that a pattern must be independent of any language, compiler or platform in order to qualify.
Since code-behind is a pure language feature (and therefore a compiler feature), code-behind can't violate *any* design pattern.

Code-behind i.e. a `partial` class, is a crucial part of WPF: not everything can be implemented in XAML. The conclusion that if you can't implement it in XAML, dependency properties or complex logic in general for example, it must be in the *View Model* is very wrong.
In fact most view related framework code is written in C#. XAML is primarily meant to layout the UI: it visually reflects the tree structure of the UI and excels C# in terms of readability in this context. Also some tasks are easier using XAML, like creating a `DataTemplate` for example. This are only reasons to *prefer* XAML over C# when writing UI related code. XAML can never replace C#.

The solution to your problem is to show the dialog from code-behind e.g. by implementing a click handler.

To add more flexibility, the following example makes use of a `RoutedCommand` to replace a click handler.
This way, the dialog can be shown from any control that is child of the control that defines the corresponding `CommandBinding` (in this case the `MainWindow`):

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```cs
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
  public static RoutedUICommand ShowAddProductDialogCommand { get; } = new RoutedUICommand(
    "Show the product dialog", 
    nameof(ShowAddProductDialogCommand), 
    typeof(MainWindow));

  private IDialogService DialogService { get; }

  public MainWindow(IDialogService dialogService)
  {
    InitializeComponent();

    this.DialogService = dialogService;
    var dialogCommandBinding = new CommandBinding(ShowDialogCommand, ExecuteShowDialogCommand, CanExecuteShowDialogCommand);
    this.CommandBindings.Add(dialogCommandBinding);
  }

  private void ExecuteShowDialogCommand(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e) 
    => this.DialogService.ShowAddProductDialog();

  private void CanExecuteShowDialogCommand(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e) 
    => e.CanExecute = true;
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```xml
<Window>
  <local:ProductListView />
</Window>
```

**ProductListView.xaml**

```xml
<UserControl>
  <Button Content="Show Dialog"
          Command="{x:Static local:MainWindow.ShowAddProductDialogCommand}" />
</UserControl>
```

**IDialogService.cs**

```cs
public interface IDialogService
{
  void ShowAddProductDialog();

  // Add more methods - one for each dialog.
  // Each method knows how to configure and show the dialog window.
}
```

**DialogService.cs**

```cs
public class DialogService : IDialogService
{
  private Func<IProductAddViewModel> AddProductDialogViewModelFactory { get; }

  // Inject a factory for each dialog/ContentTemplate to create new view models for each dialog.
  // Add more factories - one for each dialog/dialog view model.
  public DialogService(Func<IProductAddViewModel> addProductDialogViewModelFactory)
  {
    this.AddProductDialogViewModelFactory = addProductDialogViewModelFactory;
  }

  public void ShowAddProductDialog()
  {
    IProductAddViewModel dialogDataContext = this.AddProductDialogViewModelFactory.Invoke();
    var dialog = new DialogWindow() 
    {    
      DataContext = dialogDataContext,
      Content = dialogDataContext
    };
    
    dialog.ShowDialog();
  }
}
```

**App.xaml.cs**

```cs
// Register the factory for the DialogService
services.AddSingleton<Func<IProductAddViewModel>>(serviceProvider => serviceProvider.GetService<IProductAddViewModel>);
```

Comment: First I want you to know I really appreciate  you help and don't get me wrong, but I think you misunderstand me or I am just stupid. In your example I can't see you passing ViewModel type to dialog, there is no Dependecy Injection, also you passed dataContext and didn't use it anywhere (on purpose? idk). I can't understand how your example know what view should display in a dialog. What I understand is only that I should not be afraid of using view's code behind. Maybe is simply too much for me

Comment: I forgot to show the command handlers in the MainWindow.xaml.cs. I have added them. Dependency injection or DataContext are both not relevant. The point is that the example gives you an option to show the dialog from the view using a RoutedCommand. The example shows a UserControl that uses the ShowDialogCommand, which is defined in the MainWindow class, to request a dialog. The MainWindow registers the command handlers to handle the RoutedCommand. In the ExecuteShowDialogCommand handler, the original example simply displays a MessageBox. You can use your DialogService instead.

Comment: I have modified the example to make the MainWIndow accept a IDialogService to pick the dialog. I have also modified the DialogService to give you an idea how it should work. The ExecuteShowDialogCommand method now uses the IDialogService to show the associated dialog.

Comment: Damn, now everything is clear for me and I finally understand this. I made it work for my app. I only had to change a little my DI, but everything is working perfectly. Thank you so, so much for help and your patience! If you can edit your post and fix naming of "AddProductDialogViewModelFactory" in DialogService.cs 'couse its different in ShowAddProductDialog() method. Simply to be clear for other newbie like me ;)

Comment: I have fixed the typo, thanks. If your dialog view models like the `IProductAddViewModel` have constructor dependencies too, you can replace the `Func<T>` with an abstract factory class (see Abstract Factory pattern). This factory itself can request the required dependencies to construct the view model class via its constructor. Then register this factory (and its interface) with your IoC container as usual.

Comment: oh, wow. this got really verbose. I need clarification: my VM has a method, which user can trigger by click (command, bound to button, as usual). that method sometimes requires additional input from user and then must continue execute next line. additional input is a custom dialog. can you please clarify, @BionicCode, how such dialog can be opened from method, and how it can provide method with necessary input?

Comment: @ASh Can you clarify the scenario please? You may invent some scenario to explain why the user can invoke a command when the view model is not in the appropriate state to handle it? Shouldn't CanExecute return false until the command can actually execute?

Comment: I just want to understand suggested architecture better: case `void process() { var result1 = run_step1(); if (result1 == "expired") { /*show dialog to renew password which expired*/} run_step2() }`. (I regularly see such dialog with my GUI git client due to git server policies)

Comment: @ASh Is this a real problem? Passwords usually are valid for a session. If the user can click a button he obviously is logged in. Otherwise he must renew the password before he can operate the GUI. If this would be a server-client scenario you have session tokens. It is not possible that the request expires while it executes. What kind of UX would this be if the user is required to renew his password every second? Why would a password expire while a user is logged in anyway? Maybe you simply tell me what your problem is and why you believe that my answer is wrong?

Comment: user log in on day1, gets a token. clones repo. user works with repo on day1-day30. user works with local directory on day31, tries to fetch updates (`process()` method) and gets "token expired" message. user has to enter new password before fetch is executed

Comment: @ASh This is a classic scenario where you would avoid the invalid state first by checking the validity of the token. You can get the expiration date and prompt for a new token if it is expired - before you execute the operation. Generally you would roll back when something went wrong during the execution. There is no good reason to actively wait for user interaction. User interaction is illegal then report an error. Roll back if necessary. Let user fix the error and start a new request. Did I pass? Or do you want to sell me that the view model must show dialogs? Is that really your point?

Comment: There is this thing called input validation and context validation to avoid your exact problem.

Comment: My point is very simple: I had a follow-up question. It is a question and answer site. I thought, you can expand your answer to address additional case. You sort of did, but with strange accusations mixed-in. I formed my own opinion, which I didn't and won't try to "sell"

Comment: @ASh If I'm wrong then I apologize. The way your question was phrased gives me the feeling that you want to proof something in a somehow offensive manner. It doesn't came over like a normal question. And had some experience with you asking some questions in a very provocative style obviously aiming to tell me that my opinion was wrong, but not in a nice way. If this time this was a serious question then you deserve a serious reply. Only in this case I hope you accept my apology.

Comment: @ASh I have quite some experience and I never had to interact with the user from the view model or model. The idea alone is totally wrong by definition. If MVVM wants you to have a view model that doesn't depend on the view, then we obviously must find a way to avoid having the view model to communicate with the view (or the user, who is part of the view domain). Applying GUI design rules and some well established design principles, we can easily avoid this. Most of the time it only requires to think from a different or new perspective.

Comment: @ASh From what I know of your problem, I would design my application in a way that your rendered scenario won't occur: disallow interacting within an expired session. Most application will simply log out the user and throw a login view at him. Business logic and view model should never depend on the view. If they don't depend on the view they can't depend on the user. The user can't interact with the view model. The user can only interact with the GUI. The boundaries of such an architecture are very clear.

Comment: @ASh I would validate the context by validating the session token. If it is invalid I would close the session. If the user initiated operation requires user input, then I would make the presence of this data mandatory. I would "wait" for the required input and validate it: I would block this operation until all the required input is collected and valid and therefore the view model is in a valid state and able to execute the operation. This would make the application robust and eliminates annoying dialog interaction (from the user perspective).